# Makefile claims object file is up to date, but it does not exist

Tags: c, bash, makefile

I have this makefile (I cut out the irrelevant parts):

```
CC = gcc
EXEC = mtm_cm
LIB = -L. -lmtm
DEBUG = -g
CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -pedantic-errors -DNDEBUG $(DEBUG)
OBJS = command_parser.o course_manager.o grade_data.o student.o \
 grade_sheet_data.o print_utilities.o semester.o string_utilities.o

$(EXEC): $(OBJS) main.o
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) $(OBJS) main.o $(LIB) -o $@

... here the $(OBJS) targets are found ...

tests: $(OBJS) student_test grade_data_test

grade_data_test: tests/grade_data_test.o
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) $(OBJS) tests/$@.o $(LIB) -o $@

student_test: tests/student_test.o
    $(CC) $(DEBUG) $(OBJS) tests/$@.o $(LIB) -o $@

tests/student_test.o: tests/student_test.c tests/new_test_utilities.h \
 student.h list.h grade_sheet_data.h

tests/grade_data_test.o: tests/grade_data_test.c tests/new_test_utilities.h \
 grade_data.h grade_sheet_data.h list.h
```

Everything works normally, except the grade_data part.
That is, if I call `make`, the executable `mtm_cm` is created, and if I call `make tests`, then `student_test` is  created, but not `grade_data_test`.
Instead, I get an error:

```
... former successful compilations ...
gcc -g command_parser.o course_manager.o grade_data.o student.o grade_sheet_data.o print_utilities.o semester.o string_utilities.o tests/grade_data_test.o -L. -lmtm -o grade_data_test
gcc: tests/grade_data_test.o: No such file or directory
```

But it did not merely skip the dependency of the target `grade_data_test`. Instead, let us run `make tests/grade_data_test.o --debug=v`, and get the output:

```
...
Finished prerequisites of target file `tests/grade_data_test.o'.
Must remake target `tests/grade_data_test.o'.
Successfully remade target file `tests/grade_data_test.o'.
make: `tests/grade_data_test.o' is up to date.
```

But the file does not exist.
The directories have enough permission, and I don't have directories with the same name as files.

Can you help me find out the solution?

Comment: Is there any whitespace on the line immediately following the `tests/grade_data_test.o` rule?

Comment: I suspect you need a compilation command line on the line after the last line shown in the `makefile`.

Comment: @aschepler indeed that was the problem! Now it works, thank you!

Comment: a question:  Why did you not include the `main.o` as one of the object files?

Comment: what is the `A` line after the definition of the macro `CFLAGS`?

Comment: How are you invoking this make file?   Normally there is a `all` (phony) target that would list the executable files as dependencies,  Strongly suggest using the `gcc` compiler to generate the 'dependency' files then `#include` those dependency files then your actual compile recipe (which you did not post, so we have to assure your trying to use the default) would include the appropriate dependency file.  Similar to: `%.o:%.c %.d` followed by the actual compile statement.

Comment: to avoid having the macros evaluated more that once.  define them using `:=` rather that `=`

Comment: regarding: `... here the $(OBJS) targets are found ...`  will cause the make utility to fail.  Suggest prefixing the line with: `#` as that is the comment marker used by `make`

Comment: @user3629249 Because I use the same macro for compiling other programs with a main() function, so I must exclude the main.o in order to compile them.

Comment: Thank you, people, for your advice. The problem was solved, all good, thanks to aschepler, above.